# Max from a list of all shortest paths between two nodes

Tags: python, networkx, shortest-path

I have an undirected graph

I would like to calculate the max from a list of all the shortest path lengths between two nodes in the network, any ideas how I can do that?

Comment: What does maximum shortest path means? Shortest path between which nodes?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear, I clarified. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want the graph diameter which is the maximum of all-pairs shortest paths. 
https://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.distance_measures.diameter.html

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to consider some subset of vertices for source and target, you might do something like:

```
# Change these to fit your needs
sources = G.nodes()     # For example, sources = [0,1,4]
targets = G.nodes()

max_shortest_path = None
for (s,t) in itertools.product(sources, targets):
    if s == t: continue # Ignore
    shortest_paths = list(nx.all_shortest_paths(G, s, t))
    path_len = len(shortest_paths[0])
    if max_shortest_path is None or path_len > len(max_shortest_path[0]):
        max_shortest_path = list(shortest_paths)    # Copy shortest_paths list
    elif path_len == len(max_shortest_path[0]):
        max_shortest_path.extend(shortest_paths)
```

Afterward, `max_shortest_path` is a list.  All elements of `max_shortest_path` are lists of equal length.

`len(max_shortest_path[0])` will get you the *length* of the maximal shortest path in the graph.

The elements of `max_shortest_path` are the paths of this length.